# Is this an edge use of "toted" or a typo for "touted"?

Tags: meaning

This certainly seems like a typo, but the circumstances make it so hard to accept that I thought I'd check whether there's an unusual usage that I'm unaware of.

In the novel *The Liar's Dictionary* by Eley Williams, I encountered this phrase (broader context to follow): "Whether a dictionary should *register* or *fix* the language is often toted as a qualifier." I was struck by the use of "tote"—it seems like it ought to be simply a typo for "tout." And yes, typos are wildly common in all books, especially "these days." But I have a hard time believing it since the poetic injustice in this instance would be staggering: It's in a book *about* meticulous relationships with words, in the midst of a preface riffing on the extended metaphor of a "perfect dictionary," and in a paragraph starting "That a perfect dictionary should be *right* is obvious," and an immediate context about rigid and proscriptive control of language. That a typo should slip into *this* sentence of all sentences seems—well, not inconceivable, but wildly coincidental. And even "tout" seems like a not unproblematic reading, given the "Whether" construction; it seems like a meaning akin to "debate" might be appropriate.

So, every dictionary I can find gives only the expected verb definitions of "tote"—either carry, or "tote up" a sum. But **is there perhaps an obscure meaning of *tote* that fits this sentence?**

Here's a broader context:

> Preface
>
> Let us imagine that you possess a perfect personal dictionary. A, the, whatever. Not a *not-imperfect* dictionary but the best dictionary that could ever exist for you.
>
> ....
>
> To consider a dictionary to be "perfect" requires a reflection upon the aims of such a book. *Book* is a shorthand here.
>
> The perfect dictionary should not be playful for its own sake, for fear of alienating the reader and undermining its usefulness.
>
> That a perfect dictionary should be *right* is obvious. It should contain neither spelling nor printing errors, for example, and should not make groundless claims. It should not display any bias in its definitions except those made as the result of meticulous and rigorous research. But already this is far too theoretical—we can be more basic than that: it is crucial that the book covers open, at least, and that the ink is legible upon its pages. Whether a dictionary should *register* or *fix* the language is often toted as a qualifier. *Register*, as if words are like so many delinquent children herded together and counted in a room; *fixed*, as if only a certain number of children are allowed access to the room, and then the room is filled with cement.
>
> The perfect preface should not require so many mixed metaphors.

(I suppose that one other explanation is that it's an *intentional typo*, introduced as a kind of "Persian flaw" on a page decrying "spelling and printing errors." Seems like the kind of two-layered (two-faced?) stunt that might be expected from something that wanders about an extended metaphor about perfection, then coyly draws attention to its own apparent shortcomings ("Oops, I guess I mixed one metaphor too many. Silly me!"), or that avers solemnly that a work "should not be playful for its own sake," then buries metaphorical children in cement, or (in the bit I omitted) waxes fantastic about "a typeface that would be played by Jeremy Brett or Romaine Brooks—a typeface with cheekbones," or daydreams about how leather covers, flicked with a thumbnail, "make a satisfying *fnuck-fnuck* sound."

But still implausible.

Comment: Perhaps *carried around/taken along (like a tote bag)* with every definition/discussion of what a dictionary should be. *Tout* seems more appropriate for a dictionary/usage guide that boasts it does one or the other.

Comment: Clearly, it should be: touted. Language can be touted as something but a language cannot be toted around like a bag. Please. Unless it's poetry or a song. [By the way, I don't find that writing particularly appealing or even good.] Sounds non-native: "To consider a dictionary to be "perfect" requires a reflection"?? Give me strength.

Comment: The sentence doesn't seem to fit. Whatever the correct verb is, without a by-phrase it's unclear who the caveator doing the toting / touting / spouting / shouting is, which introduces dissonance into the text. I'd want 'There is, of course, the ongoing debate regarding whether a dictionary should be descriptive or prescriptive'. // 'All words [being] infinitely polysemous', we'd all need our own dedicated perfect dictionaries, which would magically update every time we became aware of new (to us and/or global) shades of meaning. And include millions of caveats.

Comment: Please provide more information about the book. What is the title and where is the link?

Comment: [This Google Books query](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is+often+toted+as+a%22) specifically asks **Did you mean: "is often touted as a"**, but it does return several other instances using ***toted*** instead of ***touted***. So it's far from "unknown" (but as [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+often+toted+as+a%2Cis+often+touted+as+a&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20often%20touted%20as%20a%3B%2Cc0) shows, it's even farther from ***in common use***). Just accept it as "non-mainstream" and move on.

Comment: IMHO, touted makes sense whilst totes does not.

Comment: @Lambie Edited author Eley Williams into the question. It's a new book this year, considering it as an Xmas gift, and I've been reading a Kindle edition, but the Amazon "look inside" feature seems to confirm that it's not an OCR issue and "toted" is in the print edition. [Here's a review](https://www.npr.org/2021/01/06/953627624/the-liars-dictionary-is-a-delight-from-a-to-z).

Comment: This is POB unless someone contacts the author, or finds an obscure sense of 'tote' in OED (I'm not sure that makes it acceptable).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yeah, the latter is what I was hoping for. (Though I also agree: if you're going to use a usage that 99.99% of people don't recognize off the top of their head and have to go on an Indiana-Jones-style hunt for, then serves you right for it to be written off as a typo.)

Comment: Is this the author's typo or a transcription error? *That a perfect dictionary should be right is obvious. It should contain neither spelling **not** printing errors, for example, and should not make groundless claims.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat Wups, that's mine (not the first in that transcription attempt). Despite heightened awareness, I made typos in quoting a passage about typos that probably contains a typo!

Comment: @AndyBonner As long as you don't do it when carving in stone, which is known as making a *litho.*

Comment: Ok, so, maybe tote is a non-dictionary Mountweazel. By the way, I once worked for a chamber of commerce, in charge of publications. I inserted the term "coke dealers" into listing of business codes (SIC codes). Well, by the time they realized it, it had already been published, and, "coke dealer" is not just about cocaine.

Comment: @Lambie It wasn't in 1815. [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=coke+dealer&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccoke%20dealer%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Try "coke and coal dealers". Geesus. Nrgams prove nothing. The point is that it isn't in the SIC codes, a business. That is the collocation. Not a bunch of books via google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe *tote* is correct, and yes, there’s an obscure meaning of *tote* that suits this sentence.

Here’s a definition from *Webster’s New International Dictionary of the English Language* (Second Edition, Unabridged, 1939):

> **tote,** *v., t., & i.* [see TOTE the total, 4th TOT] To tot; total; reckon; count. *Colloq.*

You can see that definition in *tote*’s second to last entry in the image:

[image: definition entry for tote from Webster’s New International Dictionary of the English Language* (Second Edition, Unabridged, 1939]

Let’s go with *reckon*:

> *Whether a dictionary should register or fix the language is often reckoned as a qualifier.*

And now let’s look at a definition for *reckon*:

> **reckon** *v.*
> **6. a.** *transitive*. With complement, or with *as*, *for*, or *to be*. To regard, consider, or hold (a person or thing) to be something
> specified, or to be of a specified nature, quality, importance,
> etc.
>  <sub>[selected example usages]
>  c1850    *Arabian
> Nights* (Rtldg.) 181    He was reckoned one of the richest
> merchants in the city.
>  1870    J. YEATS *Nat. Hist. Commerce*
> 108    Quite a fourth of the soil is reckoned as
> unproductive.
>  1939    *Fortune Nov.* 62/2    A full year
> is reckoned as essential for making a civilian into a good
> soldier.
>  Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com)
> (login required)</sub>

Lastly, let’s plug in *regarded*:

> *Whether a dictionary should register or fix the language is often regarded as a qualifier.*

I think this is much more plausible than a typo.

Comment: Yay! That's a plausible an explanation as any. Though I'd discounted it since most uses of that sense seem to focus on "toting *up*" multiple items. I wonder whether usage shifted. I'd love to find an example of it used for a singular item...

Comment: @AndyBonner: You could swap in *counted* instead — if that brings it closer: *Whether a dictionary should register or fix the language is often counted as a qualifier.*

Comment: No. That's the wrong sense of 'reckon'. It doesn't correspond.

Comment: The online m-w has that meaning for *tote*: : ADD, TOTAL —usually used with *up*. But I think don't think this meaning of *reckon* is the figurative one as in *I reckon*. [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tote)

Comment: @DjinTonic  I tote you're right ...  I reckonally agree.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth who's toting whose water here?

Comment: "A **tote board** (or totalisator/totalizator) is a numeric or alphanumeric display used to convey information, typically at a race track (to display the odds or ..." Wiki

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: What do you deem to be the corresponding sense of *reckon*, and why?

Comment: I think *reckon* in the *Webster's* definition pictured is just *count, estimate*, or *compute* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recko)

Comment: Now I'm thinking that this could be the right meaning for *tote*, but with the meaning of *Whether a dictionary should register or fix the language is often **added** as a qualifier.*

Comment: @DjinTonic: As noted, *count* works too: *Whether a dictionary should register or fix the language is often counted as a qualifier.* Note, too, that this is a passive voice construction. Active: *[People] often count whether a dictionary should register or fix the language as a qualifier [for what makes a perfect dictionary].*

Comment: @TinfoilHat True. The problem is that the resulting sentences from all our attempts are unsatisfying because nothing really "clicks"-- at least to me. *Qualifier* is a strange choice.

Comment: @DjinTonic Agreed. My paraphrase of what I *reckon* the sentence to be getting at is: "A dictionary's ability to 'register' or 'fix' the language is often considered an attribute for qualification as a dictionary." Which makes *qualifier* an odd choice, given its own distinct linguistic meaning. I should also say, though I've accepted this answer as the "best effort," I'm also dubious about the "The definition for X gives Y, and the definition for Y gives Z, which fits nicely" chaining. Until I see proof in the wild, I doubt that one can "tote" a single specimen.

Comment: @AndyBonner: A qualifier is that which qualifies, or *characterizes by naming an attribute*. These are among the attributes that might characterize one’s own perfect dictionary: *[It] should be right... It should contain neither spelling nor printing errors.... It should not display any bias in its definitions... it is crucial that the book covers open, at least, and that the ink is legible upon its pages.* For some, that it should be prescriptive (“fixed”) would number among the qualifiers. For others, that it should be descriptive (“register”) would number among the qualifiers.

Comment: @TinfoilHat  (I believe) and I heard back from the author today. It's fitting that Tinfoil edit this answer, since she wrote "In short, my intended reading of the word was in line with poster TinfoilHat's answer."

Comment: @DjinTonic: Note that after she says my answer is in line with her intended reading, she goes on to support just about everyone else's reading as well :-). I did get permission from her to post her reply to our queries. I'm not sure how or where to do that, though. I kinda think it should be its own answer to the question. I will ask our moderator for advice.

Comment: @TinfoilHat. I agree with all you said. :-).

Comment: @tchrist: We received a reply regarding the use of *toted* from the author herself, as well as permission to post the reply here. Should it be posted as an answer to the original question? Or?

Answer (score 2):

Focusing on this other meaning of to *tote* (to *total/add*), I think the sentence could make (some) sense as:

> *Whether a dictionary should register or fix the language is often **added / added in** as a qualifier.*

> **tote** (v.)
>
> ADD, TOTAL —usually used with up
>
> *toted up his accomplishments* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tote)

> To add up; to calculate a total. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tote)

> Informal
>
> 1. To determine the total of; add up.
> 2. To sum up; summarize. [AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=tote)

Comment: Again, my misgiving is that this always seems to regard *arriving* at a total of a number of things (TinfoilHat's 1939 entry makes it pretty clear that the etymology is simply an abbreviation of "total," not unlike the modern slang "totes" for "totally"). This reading would depend on implying a number of other unspecified "qualifiers," and it still seems odd to apply it to the individual entry rather than the group. (It might seem more likely if it were "is often toted *among* its qualifiers.) No, at the moment I think it's an (ironic) typo.

Comment: @AndyBonner I think the ELU totalizer is currently displaying odds in favor of it being a typo. *Criterion* makes more sense than *qualifier* to me.

Comment: I'm seeing "toted" used for "touted" in Google Books -- are these all typos?

Comment: Looking at FumbleFingers' list, I'm inclined to say it's simply a not-uncommon usage error. If it were more widespread it would be a secondary usage, but I'm not sure it adds up (totes up?) to that yet. And see, again, I'd find a casual error unlikely in a book and a passage so self-consciously concerned with usage and definitions.

Comment: [Here's one example from Google Books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Use_and_Abuse_of_Police_Power_in_Ame/6sm-DgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22toted+as%22&pg=PA181&printsec=frontcover): *Because the American police officer represents a decentralized government, they are public servants who are often toted as armed, occupying forces.* I can't get any synonym of *tout* to fit well here. It means *seen as* or *regarded as*. (Search *toted as* in Books.)

Comment: @TinfoilHat *Tout* works for me in this example: "to make much of : PROMOTE, TALK UP"  I don't know what's going on with the *tote*. That is the usual sense I see when I encounter *tout*.

Comment: [Here's another](https://www.csmonitor.com/Books/Book-Reviews/2008/1023/the-tyranny-of-oil): *Its subsequent breakup by a Supreme Court ruling in 1911 is toted as marking the end of an era and a distant moment in corporate management. Right? Wrong...* *Touted* doesn't work here.

Comment: *Touted* works: *held up as/promoted/considered*

Comment: @DjinTonic: Where did you get *considered* as a synonym for *touted*?

Comment: @TinfoilHat Perhaps that's too weak. "The new mayor was touted as the answer to the city's problems during his campaign." It seems OK for the meaning of the OP's sentence if "toted" is a typo. "Promote" is one definition. // Do you think some folks think *toted* is a synonym for *touted* rather than being a typo for it?

Comment: @DjinTonic: If they do, and if dictionary entries are considered descriptive rather than prescriptive, then they would be right, eventually, anyway. But before that, ask why they are doing that, and look at the etymology for *reckon* and *count* — it's the same whether it means *calculate*,  *number*,  *regard*,  or *consider*. There's no place for *consider* in the definition of *tout*.

Answer (score 2):

> is there perhaps an obscure meaning of tote that fits this sentence?

Not in the OED:

> **tote** colloquial (originally U.S.).
>
> 1. transitive. To carry as a burden or load; to transport, esp. supplies to, or timber, etc. from, a logging-camp or the like. Also, to wear or carry regularly as part of one's equipment; to take (a person) with one; to tote fair, to carry one's fair share; figurative to act or deal fairly or honestly.

Whereas

> **tout**
>
> 3.a. intransitive. To look out busily for customers; to solicit custom, employment, etc. importunately; also, U.S., Australian, etc., to canvass for votes.
>
> **b. transitive  (a) To importune (a person) in a touting manner;  (b) to solicit custom for (a thing), to try to sell; also (U.S.) in extended sense, to recommend.**

It's a mistake.